# Flutter Vibration Packages capable of forwarding vibration to Watches?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, vibration

I want to build a cross platform app(IOS/Android) that notifies users via HapticFeedback whenever a timer ends. Given the nature of the app, users that have a Watch connected to their device would benefit greatly from having the Watch vibrate and not the phone.

Question:

1. Do watches such as the "Apple Watch" and the "Samsung Galaxy Watch" automatically route notifications coming from a third-party app to the Watch or would the app need to specifically target the Watch in order to make it vibrate?
2. Would a package like "flutter_vibrate" be capable of making the Watches Vibrate?

Answer (score 0):

The companion app that pairs with the watch needs to be set to either:

1. Forward system notifications to the watch
   or
2. Specifically let the app in question send notifications

Therefore, as long as the companion app controlling the watch is listening for system notification and forwarding them to the watch, the flutter_vibrate package will provide HapticFeedback to the watch